# Webview doesn't load the entire website

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I tried to load a website using webview, the page does load. However, the page doesn't load everything. I got php part and a Youtube vídeo but It didn't appear. This is my code:

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {


public ChatFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);

    String url = "mywebpath/index.php"; // It has the http part
    WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.chat);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }
    else {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    return view;
}
```

This is the website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iORiW.jpg

And this is the webview result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aGu4.png

Thank so much for your attention

P.S. The chat starts with php part and then appear a div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh ! You must create your website for version mobile

EG:

vsersion Browser: [for Browser](https://www.facebook.com/)

version Mobile: [for mobile](https://m.facebook.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it!!!

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
String url = "mywebpath/index.php"; // It has the http part
WebView mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.chat);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().getPluginState(); 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); 
} else { 
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON); 
}
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
 }
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
return view;
}
```

in AndroidMainfest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

if it does not work. Try this. (replace mWebview.loadUrl)

```
mWebview.loadData(url, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Or

```
mWebview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", url, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```